# Fire JavaScript from Upload Control Inside a Template Field in GridView ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview which contains a column containing a HTMLInput File Control (Upload Button), Also We have an image here, Here is the Code:

```
   <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible='<%# Bind("IsfileUplo") %>'>
        <div>
        <table>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                  <input id="Upload1" type="file" name="file" onchange="javascript:previewFile(this)" runat="server" accept="image/*" />
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
         </div>
         <div>
            <table>
               <tr>
                 <td>
                  <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="" Width="120px"></asp:Label>
                  </td>
              </tr>
           </table>
           </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

After running website we have something like this:

[image: New Item Template in Each Row]

As you can see there an Item Template with those controls in each row. Now I need to fire previewFile() javascript function which gets upload button and image ID and then will do something. Here is the code:

```
        function previewFile() {
            var preview = document.querySelector('#<%=Image2.ClientID %>');
            var file = document.querySelector('#<%=Upload1.ClientID %>').files[0];}
```

The problem is here, It can not detect Image2 and Upload1 Controls inside Item Template of Grid View. I need to get the image path of selected picture with upload control and show it in image control in client side using this script. But I can not pass correct Control IDs to get it to work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change Your `onchange="previewFile()"` to `onchange="previewFile(this)"`. It will target specific control (which You clicked) and search inside `ItemTemplate` (`parentNode` of clicked `input type="file"`) for first `Image` control.

aspx :

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <input id="Upload1" type="file" name="file" onchange="previewFile(this)" runat="server" accept="image/*" />
     <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

js :

```
function previewFile(ele) {
             var fl = ele.files[0];  //get selected file
             var img = ele.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];  //get 1st image control in ItemTemplate where is Your input file is.
             img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(fl); //preview image without uploading
         }
```

btw. This is just previewing selected image. It's not uploaded.

**Updated :** (new code adapted to changed question)

```
function previewme(ele) {
            var fl = ele.files[0];
            var placeHolder = ele.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
            var div = placeHolder.getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
            var tbl = div.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
            var img = tbl.rows[0].cells[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
            var lbl = tbl.rows[0].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
            img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(fl);
            lbl.innerHTML = 'File choosed';
        }
```

Comment: interested... I tested before provide answer. Still can't recognize id's? btw. my answer just find controls and show image :(

Comment: Yeah Your Codes' Logic is correct and It should work, But I do not know where is the problem :(

Comment: I think parent node is the problem, Image control is a part of Grid View Row not Input Control. in your code the Parent will be the Input control and I think here should be the problem.

Comment: well, no... Input and Image controls are child of GridView Row Cell (ItemTemplate)... so, when I use `var img = ele.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];` parent control of `ele` (in this case Your `input`) will be gridview row cell (`ItemTemplate`) where are placed both controls (if You open Page Source, You'll se both controls inside `td`). Try this link, I put app temporary, http://atest.neprog.com/

Comment: I get it to work nelek :) But I removed all of extra things, for example these control were inside a table inside a placeholder! and now I have another problem, I just add a label control and I use this code inside script to get it: var label = ele.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]; but I can not access the textcontent :(

Comment: How You try to access the textcontent? example : `var label = ele.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]; alert(label.innerHTML);` ... it's show me content. btw. You put that label In the same `ItemTemplate`.. for example `<ItemTemplate><input type="file" /><asp:Image ... /><asp:Label ....></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>` ? If Your `label` is outside of that `ItemTemplate` then js will not find him.

Comment: I'm not as amateur as you think :) Yeah the label is inside ItemTemplate, I user label.textcontent to change the label's text and it is not working.

Comment: no, no, noooo .... I never think something like that ... sorry if sound like that :(

Comment: Please Look at updated question, Now How Can I access that Image and Label?

Comment: I see... need few minutes

Comment: I found it nelek, we should use ParentNode several times to get the correct Parent, ele.parentnode.parentnode.parentnode.Getelement etc

Comment: Yes There is example if You need : `function previewme(ele) {
            var fl = ele.files[0];
            var placeHolder = ele.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
            var div = placeHolder.getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
            var tbl = div.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
            var img = tbl.rows[0].cells[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
            var lbl = tbl.rows[0].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
            img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(fl);
            lbl.innerHTML = 'File choosed';
        }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84928/discussion-between-stranger-and-nelek).